# How can I get a convert a Graphics object to a Bitmap (or access it as a Bitmap)

Tags: c#, bitmap

I know the whole

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100,100) ;
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp) ;
```

But that is not what I need to do. Essentially what I am trying to do is slightly modify how something is draw on the screen (it is a rectangle with a line in the middle). I need to change the background of the rectangle (which I could do with a pixel comparison or other similar method).

If I could somehow turn it into a bitmap. There is no way (that I can tell to get/set/modify) the graphics object on the pixel level.

Comment: you want to change the background color of the bitmap image?

Comment: I am sorry I must not be being clear. I need to change the background of a rectangle that has been already drawn to a graphics object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bob Powell has written an excellent article about accessing image bits directly.

https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a for loop like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
    {
        var pixel = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);
        //do stuff with pixel here :)
    }
}
```

EDIT: After seeing Tilak's comment, if performance is an issue for you then he is right! (Thanks, I did not know about LockBits! +1) Some examples can be found on the [MS BitmapData Class page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata). However, if this seems complicated the above method should do the trick :)

Comment: this is very slow. for faster retreival, lockBits is better using P/Invoke

Answer (score 0):

Once you've used the Graphics, just save the Bitmap - the changes made with the graphics are made to the bitmap.